# Deploy Azure Logic App to Secure Storage Account inside Azure Landing Zone - Corp

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

We've recently deployed Azure Landing Zones via Terraform with all its policies.  We are now looking to deploy a Azure Logic App that utilizes a Secure Storage Account, and deploy it into the Landing Zone -> Corp management group.

This management group has a policy that all PaaS services must have public network access disabled.

I've tried following multiple articles that supposedly go through how to perform this, but it seems at the end they have Public Network Access set to 'Select Networks' and not 'Disabled', which goes against the policy.

[MS Deploy Stardard logic app to private storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/deploy-single-tenant-logic-apps-private-storage-account)

[Deploying Standard Logic App to Storage Account behind firewall](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/deploying-standard-logic-app-to-storage-account-behind-firewall/ba-p/2626286)
[Medium - Deploying Azure standand logic app](https://medium.com/@t.costantini89/deploy-an-azure-standard-logic-app-with-vnet-integration-and-a-storage-account-behind-private-4bbd5fabe6e1)

The other problem is that most of these build the resources and then change them, which of course doesn't really work well with Terraform as the next running of TF will squawk!

Anybody ever deploy a Logic App to a secure Storage Account within Azure Landing Zone?

Comment: Have you tried any configuration so far any blockers @MattS?

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally got it working.  Not easy and you'll need to create a separate terraform directory and run it locally.  After the deployment, you'll be changing settings which terraform doesn't like and will want to change them back, so I ran this local out of a subdirectory of my Azure Landing Zone repository.

Follow this article with the changes below:
[Deploy an Azure Standard Logic App to secure Storage](https://medium.com/@t.costantini89/deploy-an-azure-standard-logic-app-with-vnet-integration-and-a-storage-account-behind-private-4bbd5fabe6e1)

1. If deploying to the Landing Zone -> Corp management group, you'll need to temporarily change two policy assignments.  Go to the group -> Policy -> Assignments.  Search for 'PaaS' and select the one about Public Access.  Edit the Assignment, go to Parameters, Unselect the checkbox, and change the parameter for App Service and Storage to 'Audit'.
2. As stated in the article, you will need to run this in three phases.  First create the RG and the subnets.
3. Next create the storage account, share, and all the private endpoints.  Make sure your subnets have at least '/27' on the mask otherwise the logic app won't work.  Also make sure you have your IP in the locals as that is needed to create the share.
4. Lastly, create the Logic App and Private Endpoint.
5. After deployment, check it out in the Azure portal and create a simple test workflow with 'Request -> Response'.  As the Logic app is still public, you can test this in Postman from your local machine.
6. Go to the Storage Account -> Networking and Disable public access.  Restart the Logic App and retest....should still work.
7. Now go to the Logic App -> Networking and disable public access here.
8. Try to test again from Postman and it should fail.  You'll need to be on the same VNet either through a VM or if your org has VPN with ExpressRoute setup.  You should be able to use the URL of the Private Endpoint to hit it.

I hope this helps.